# Displaying Options Using Dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
   <body>
   <script type ="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
         $("#dropdown").change(function(){
            if ($("#dropdown").val()=="select"){
               $("#select").show();
               $("#insert").hide();
            }else {
               $("#select").hide();
               $("#insert").show();

            }

         });
      });
   </script>
   <select id="dropdown">
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="insert">Insert</option>
   </select>
   <hr />
   <div id="select">
      Customername<br>
      <input type="text" name="Customername" id="select">
      <br>
      StartDate<br>
      <input type="date" name="Startdate" id="select">
      <br>
      Enddate
      <br>
      <input type="date" name="EndDate" id="select">
      <br>
   </div>
   <div id="insert">
      <br>
      FromDate<br>
      <input type="date" name="Startdate" id="insert">
      <br>
      Todate
      <br>
      <input type="date" name="EndDate" id="insert">
      <br>
   </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to get Customername,StartDatedate and Enddate when I click on "Select".Fromdate,Todate when I click on insert.I have tried it,but it is displaying all names without hiding what I need to add.Can you please help as I am new to HTML and jquery

Comment: so, is there anything you tried?

Comment: Haa, I tried with javascript too.But it just hides "select" names when I click on insert but not hiding "Insert" names when clicking on select.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you'd like to see either the 3 first field **or** the 2 last, you just have to trigger the `change()` event of your `select` when document is ready.

Add this to the end of your jQuery :

```
$("#dropdown").change();
```

As the code that hides or shows the fields is only executed when select's value changes, you simulate a change when document is ready and it will consider that you selected the first available option.

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/hsjo1qcL/

Comment: Hey ,Thank you guys.Actually placing <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> before jquery done my job.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `display:none` to your `insert` `div` as the default option in `select` will be **select**

```
<div id="insert" style="display:none">
      <br>
      FromDate<br>
      <input type="date" name="Startdate" id="insert">
      <br>
      Todate
      <br>
      <input type="date" name="EndDate" id="insert">
      <br>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/en8ctp3x/)**

Rest everything is good.

---

**Update**

From the comments since I see that you are getting `$ is undefined` error message you need to add jquery.js to top of the page first, It can be within `<head></head>` add below lines

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌
```

Comment: I have tried it,but it is not displaying fields of insert even though i click on insert.

Comment: Did you check the **DEMO**?

Comment: In DEMO code which I wrote is working well,but it is not working in browser.

Comment: Actually your question's code is working too, you must have a problem with JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: I seen my code is working in website what you both Guruprasad and Sebastien provided.But it is not working on desktop or my lappy.Ichecked in console and it is showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Add `jquery.js` to top of the page first, I mean within `<head></head>` write `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If it helped do upvote and accept this as answer yashwanth.. Note you can upvote multiple answers but you can accept only one.. Happy coding..